# C# Generic Repository - Unit Of Work - Thread Safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I'm currently writing an application that's relying on a database and I'm using Entity Framework (version 6.1.1 according to Nuget).

Now I've written a Repository pattern which looks like the following:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    #region Constructors

    protected RepositoryBase(IDbContext context, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    protected IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    protected readonly IDbContext Context;

    protected readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        return !query.Any() ? null : !query.Where(filter).Any() ? null : query.First(filter);
    }

    protected TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, string[] includeProperties)
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        includeProperties.Each(x => query = query.Include(x));

        return !query.Any() ? null : !query.Where(filter).Any() ? null : query.First(filter);
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        return query.AsQueryable();
    }

    protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includeProperties)
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        includeProperties.Each(x => query = query.Include(x));

        return query.AsQueryable();
    }

    protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        query = DbSet.Where(filter);

        return query;
    }

    protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, string[] includeProperties)
    {
        DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        query = DbSet.Where(filter);

        includeProperties.Each(x => query = query.Include(x));

        return query;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I do have other classes that inherit from this Repository, but I'll leave them out of scope for the moment.

Now, when I do a Get on a repository, I retrieve the data, but when I execute 2 gets call at the sime time (I just open 2 browser windows with the same url and execute them), then the following error does popup:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Here's a little image to provide as much as detailed information possible:

[image]

Now, I know that by default the Entity Framwork DbContext is not thread-safe, so I know I should do something to make it thread-safe, but I just don't know how to do this.

Can anybode provide my any guidance on how to achieve this?
Also, I don't have much experience with IDisposeable, so if you advice to implement this somewhere, it should be very kind of you to provide me some information on how to implement this.

Something important to mention is that I'm using Unity to manage my objects, of which you can find the configuration here:

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

The registration of my types is done here:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>();
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
}
```

Where the class 'OxygenDataContext' is my implementation of a 'DbContext' and 'IDbContext'.
That code can be found below (a snipped, I don't post all my elements):

```
public class OxygenDataContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    #region Constructors

    public OxygenDataContext()
        : base("Oxygen")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDbContext Members

    public IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Update**

According to me, it's Unity which is causing this behaviour since I'm using:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>();
```

This means that no new instance of the OxygenDataContext is created on every request.

Thanks for the help.

**Update 2**

When I modify the Unity confiruation like the following:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

I tought that there would be only 1 single instance, but it seems that it's not working since I keep receiving the same error.

**Update 3**

I've changed the Unity configuration to resolve the IDbContext, which is a DbContext with a 'PerResolveLifetimeManager' using the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

This would mean that every resolve call should create a new instance of the 'OxygenDataContext' or an I not correct?

In the constructor of my UnitOfWork, I'm assigning the repositories like:

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The <see cref="IDbContext"/> in which the entities are available.</param>
public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    : base(context)
{
    versioningRepository = new Repository<Versioning, IDbContext>(context, this);

    settingRepository = new Repository<Setting, IDbContext>(context, this);
    siteRepository = new VersionedRepository<Site, int, IDbContext>(context, this);
    pageRepository = new VersionedRepository<Page, int, IDbContext>(context, this);
    layoutRepository = new VersionedRepository<Layout, int, IDbContext>(context, this);
    assemblyRepository = new VersionedRepository<Assembly, int, IDbContext>(context, this);
    logRepository = new Repository<Log, IDbContext>(context, this);
}
```

So this should mean that every repository is getting it's own unique instance of the 'IDbContext', however it doesn't work as expected.

**Update 4**

I've managed to resolve my own issue, be patient as I'm writing the solution as an answer to this post.

**Update 5**

It doesn't seem to work. See here my solution which I thought was working:

I adapt my IUnitOfWork interface to implement the IDisposeable interface and than re-adjust the implementation to the following:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) { Context = null; }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I'm getting a bit lost here, so if anyone knows a solution :-)

**Update 6**

According to some posts, I need to provide some information on how that I instantiate my repositories.
So here's the explanation:

I'm using a UnitOfWork that contains all the repositories:

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The <see cref="IDbContext"/> in which the entities are available.</param>
public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    : base(context)
{
    versioningRepository = new Repository<Versioning>(context, this);

    settingRepository = new Repository<Setting>(context, this);
    siteRepository = new VersionedRepository<Site, int>(context, this);
    pageRepository = new VersionedRepository<Page, int>(context, this);
    layoutRepository = new VersionedRepository<Layout, int>(context, this);
    assemblyRepository = new VersionedRepository<Assembly, int>(context, this);
    logRepository = new Repository<Log>(context, this);
}
```

I've also tried to change the code to the following, but that doesn't work either:

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The <see cref="IDbContext"/> in which the entities are available.</param>
public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    : base(context)
{
    versioningRepository = new Repository<Versioning>(context, this);

    settingRepository = new Repository<Setting>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
    siteRepository = new VersionedRepository<Site, int>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
    pageRepository = new VersionedRepository<Page, int>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
    layoutRepository = new VersionedRepository<Layout, int>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
    assemblyRepository = new VersionedRepository<Assembly, int>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
    logRepository = new Repository<Log>(new OxygenDataContext(), this);
}
```

I still receive the error message: "The underlying provider failed on Open" with an inner exception that says "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."

You see that the constructor of the UnitOfWork does take a IDbContext instance and all the repositories are constructed with that very same instance.

I'm using Unity, and the registration of my IDbContext takes the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>();
```

In my Unity configuration, I also do register the IUnitOfWork interface:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

I do have the feeling that the error is somewhere in the Unity registration or in the UnitOfWork, but I don't seem to find it.

Comment: What's the inner exception? your image is blurry it is hard to read the inner exception.

Comment: Indeed, the image is a bit blurred. The inner exception is: "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."

Comment: Aren't you by chance sharing the same **repository** between threads? Because what you do with DbContext registration is fine. How are you resolving the repository itself?

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand your questions, isn't that clear with the updated that I've posted?

Comment: Just show the code that creates and uses the repository. I believe this is where the problem is.

Comment: I've added it in update 3, if it's not clear, just yell :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea why I'm having this behaviour?

Comment: No one will help if you don't post anything on how you create instances of your repositories. Really.

Comment: You need to provide the code where you plug in Unity into the application. My guess is that you are missing: DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));

Comment: I can confirm that I have that piece of code...

Comment: EF dataconext is not thread safe

Answer (score 6):

If I'm getting your message right, you're sharing the same DbContext among threads. That is not what DbContext is meant to be used for. Sharing data in that way is very difficult.

I don't like giving answers in the form "but why you need it", but this post looks just like that.

I would suggest you redesign the solution and to keep DbContext objects short lived - do an operation and dispose DbContext. Perform a unit of work, commit/rollback and be done with the repository. Don't forget that DbContext is going to track all objects that it fetches. You probably don't want tracked objects to live longer in memory than the transaction in which they were used.

Let the database be the point of sharing data from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do know that sharing a context is a bad idea, but I'm sitting with the Microsoft Unity in between that just seems to work against me :)

Comment: I understand. One way that I used is to make Repository<T>, where T is IDbContext. Then Repository<T> instantiates T. In that way, lifetime of IDbContext is equal to lifetime of Repository<T> object.

Comment: I have updated my question with update 2, whic so that now Unity resolves my DbContext on a 'PerRequestLifetimeManager', but it doesn't seem to work. I do need this kind of thing to make unit testing easy ... I just don't understand why Unity doesn't manage this kind of things...

Comment: When I'm going with your approach, the Repository<T> where T : IDbContext, how should Unity resolve the IDbContext interface then, and a PerRequest or without or maybe with something else?

Comment: There's no more Unity there. You instantiate Repository<OxygenDataContext> instead, so that lifetimes of the repository and the data context become the same. IDbContext is not received through the constructor anymore. On a related note, you might have to define a more specific interface, such as IOxygenDataContext, which extends IDbContext.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're not fully disposing the context here:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) { Context = null; }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

My understanding is, when you create an abstraction of dbContext (like your UoW) you want to expressly call the Garbage Collector to ensure you've cleaned up unused resources. Also, you need to dispose the dbContext not set it to null.

Example:

```
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    {
        if (!this.disposed) 
        {
            if (disposing)
               context.Dispose(); // <-- dispose
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Please give this a try :) - hopefully it helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help. I have the feeling that I'm missing some important code a bit further down, but I'm not too sure where it is. Maybe my best bet is to re-write the code from scrath. I'm tired of searching for the issue...

Comment: Sorry that didnt work :(. The issue is that you're not properly disposing your dbContext and my guess is that its because you never have a new context instance in your code. Presumably, this should be handled by injection, but try replacing the IDbContext with concretes and see if you have the problem still.

Comment: Where do you want me to replace that code? In the unit of work?

Comment: Yes. Have your Unit of Work instantiate a new instance of the context instead of injecting it. I'm guessing you won't have the same issues disposing the context. It should help you determine what's wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you register IDbContext instance. 
DbContext is not thread-safe, so you should resolve it once per request/thread (same as you do with Repository and UnitOfWork), so change your registration code to:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I think the flaw is somewhere else, but I'm just not able to track it down...

Comment: The reason it didn't help is that you have multiple issues layered one on another. Now that you've set-up IoC correctly, show us a code that actually uses IUnitOfWork.